# Retrieve characters after nth occurrence of an another with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm writing a simple bot that broadcasts messages to clients based on messages from a server. This will be done in JavaScript but I am trying to understand Regex. I've been Googling for the past hour and I've come so close but I am simply unable to solve this one.

Basically I need to retrieve everything between the **second** / and the first [. It sounds really simple but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Here's some sample code:

```
192.168.1.1:33291/76561198014386231/testName joined [linux/76561198014386231]
```

Here's the Regex I've come up with:

```
\/(.*?)\[
```

I've found lots of similar questions here on StackOverflow but most of them seem specific to a particular language or end up being too complex and I'm unable to whittle down the query.

I know this is a simple one, but I am totally stumped.

Comment: hi @brian-warren can you please state in your question the expected output? also look for typos ;)

Comment: I need to retrieve everything between the second slash / and the first brace [ in the sample code I pasted above.

The issue I am having is I am unable to select the second / character

Comment: I think this is almost the answear that you are looking for \/(?:[^\/]*\[)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.*?`. Then you could match everything but a forward slash by doing `[^\/]*`.

```
([^\/]*)\s*\[
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/XrAjPv/1)

If it needs to be after the second slash. As in the contents between the second slash and the square bracket can contain slashes. Then you could do:

```
(?:.*?\/){2}(.*)\s*\[
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/nF6nXG/1)

*Remove the `\s*` if you want to. I'm just assuming you don't care about that whitespace.*